# Store font to cookies and load from cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

hello i am student and learning codeigniter i want to save fonts to cookies and next time when user open the website then font load from cookies. the reason to store font in cookies is that the font size is up to 10 MB. so its more consuming time to open website.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a cookie is a maximum of 4Kb.
Second, this is not the proper use of a cookie, it would actually be better as localStorage, which is still not a good idea.
Third, use caching!

Comment: Thanks @ryan0319, Is it possible to store fonts to cloud and we can get access from there?

Comment: Just search the web for font hosting services, also see: https://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is probably the worst place to store something like a font: it'll get send to the server by the client on each and every request it makes ...

The font is cached by the browser. There's no need.
Moreover if you use a common font provider such as https://www.google.com/fonts (not a recommendation, just an example) and a popular font, odds are the font is already cached by the browser.